# Add additional attributes to script tag when enqueue script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need Rocket loader to ignore some specific script that I enqueue using `wp_enqueue_script()`, So I need to add `data-cfasync="false"` to the script tag. But since I enqueue a js file via `function.php`, I have no tag to add this to it.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50457/how-do-i-add-custom-attributes-to-javascript-tags-in-wordpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and this code added the attribute correctly.

Add this code snippet to your functions.php file to disable cloudfare for your specific script only. Just change YOUR_SCRIPT_HANDLE_HERE accordingly.

```
function disable_rocketship( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'YOUR_SCRIPT_HANDLE_HERE' === $handle ) {
        $tag = str_replace( 'src=', 'data-cfasync="false" src=', $tag );
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'disable_rocketship', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: you forgot to return the handle
so line 3
`$tag = "<script type=\"text/plain\"  id=\"$handle\" src=\"$src\" [YOUR ATTRIBUTE]> </script>";`